# chrome extension - How to loop with setTimeout?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to loop in async function setTimeout, to get tab index from because chrome.tabs.get sometimes crash, so, I must use loop.
But the loop stuck the browser.
How can I use loop for that?

```
// backround.js
var w=0;
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener( function(activeInfo) {
 w=0;
 setTimeout (async function (){
   while (window.w===0) {
     await chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function(tab){w=tab.index})
  };
 alert(window.w)}
            ,100);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop hangs the browser because you don't wait between the calls of chrome.tabs.get so your code generates millions of such calls in a second.

Judging by the use of `window` you're writing a classic ManifestV2 extension meaning you can't use Promise syntax of `chrome` API as well as `await`, but instead use need to the classic callback syntax or promisify the API yourself.

ManifestV2 uses callbacks:

```js
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function onActivated(info) {
  chrome.tabs.get(info.tabId, tab => {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      setTimeout(onActivated, 50, info);
      return;
    }
    // do something here
    console.log('Success');
  });
});
```

ManifestV3 uses Promises:

```js
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(async function onActivated(info) {
  let tab;
  try {
    tab = await chrome.tabs.get(info.tabId);
  } catch (e) {
    setTimeout(onActivated, 50, info);
    return;
  }
  // do something here
  console.log('Success');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that works great in v2 and v3. I wonder about the returrn, if I omit it, there is an error when trying to output tab variable, why is that?